# Find every string between quotes inside specific curly braces

Tags: regex

I'm working on a script helping me catching all my localized strings in my project and I'm stuck on a RegEx.

In the following string `{{ translateAttr title="button.add_user.title" data-disable-with="button.add_user.disabled" }}` I'd like to be able to catch "button.add_user.title" and "button.add_user.disabled" *because* my curly braces starts with `translateAttr` attribute.

So far, I've come with this rule `\{{2}translateAttr .*=(['"])(.+?)(?=(?<!\\)\1)\1 ?}{2}` but as you could see here http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=2362 it is not matching all the occurrences.

A little help here would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Patterns I'd like the regex to match too

```
{{ translateAttr title="button with \"escaped quotes\" here" data-disable-with='button with single quotes' }}
{{ translateAttr title="want this with ' single quote" "but not this one" }}
```

EDIT2 : Patterns I don't like to match

```
{{ title="because no translateAttr" }}
{{ translateAttr "because no something= attribute before" }}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex which uses the PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`

```
^(?!.*?\{{2}\h*translateAttr).*(*SKIP)(*F)|=(["'])((?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*)\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xY3sK0/17)

[Explanation](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%28%3F%3A%5C%7B%7B2%7D%5Cs*translateAttr%7C%28%3F%3C!%5CG%29%29%5Ch*[-%5Cw]*%3D%22%5CK[%5E%22]*%28%3F%3D[%5E%7B%7D]*%7D%7D%29&.submit=Explain!&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Comment: Whoa, that works ! Could you please explain a bit your regex (or some important parts I missed in my previous one to achieve this multiple catch?) Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your explanation. Unfortunately, your regex fails when a string contains ". I edited my above post to add more cases I want the pattern to catch. Thanks again. Best

Comment: Hi @avinash, thanks for your reactivity! This is much better for the two last examples http://regex101.com/r/xY3sK0/10 Unfortunately the rule catches also strings in the above examples and it shouldn't. It should only catch what is in {{ translateAttr }} case. Could you kindly have again a look? Thanks a lot

Comment: @guillaumepotier which language are you running?

Comment: I'm running PHP with preg_match_all(), mainly to analyze .js, .html and .hbs files looking for internalization keys to translate with poEdit.

Comment: use the updated regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

Comment: This is nearly perfect ! last thing, string "breaks" if there is a single quote inside and that it starts with double. Example here: http://regex101.com/r/xY3sK0/15 with title="button. ' add_user.title" case. I think that would be pretty all after that! Best

Comment: Updated. OMG, you need to provide double accepts for this answer :-)

Comment: Ahaha thanks! You Sir really are a true RegEx master! I accepted and upvoted your answer, that's the best I can do. I'll link this issue too in my code when I'll release it open source :) Best

Comment: really? My best wishes for your project :-)

Comment: Hi @Avinash, just FYI, I opened another tricky regex question here, with a bounty! Maybe your skills could help ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019696/regex-to-match-specific-functions-and-their-arguments-in-files

Comment: @guillaumepotier does the new one is based on js?

Comment: Still a PHP parser that parses javascript files.

Comment: @guillaumepotier get into here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65622/regex-help